# When I am passing a variable by value and changing it within the method its reacting as pass by reference in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying my hand at jug problem as practice in c#. When I am trying to create a tree of possible states and store them within a dictionary. Now I am depending on recursive methods to do this work .As you can see from the attached code below, after I create a root node and add it to the dictionary, I 'pass it as a value' and not by reference to another method to generate child nodes for it.now when it reaches `addToX()` method, and within it when it changes the node which has been sent as a parameter, its essentially changing the root node within the dictionary and not the local variable which is what I wish would happen so as to proceed further. Please tell me what am I doing wrong. As because the root node gets updated I can't add new nodes because of a condition that ensures that no duplicate nodes be added which essentially results in a single node in my tree.I have also tried instantiating new nodes in every object so as to make it clear that I wish to work on a local variable and not a global one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JugPuzzle
{
[Serializable]
public class probableNode
{
    int id, previd;
    List<int> nextid;
    int x, y;
    Boolean fx = false;

    public probableNode()
    { this.nextid = new List<int>(); }

    public probableNode(int id,int previd,int x,int y)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Previd = previd;
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.nextid = new List<int>();
    }

    public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public int Previd { get => previd; set => previd = value; }
    public List<int> Nextid { get => nextid; set => nextid = value; }
    public int X { get => x; set => x = value; }
    public int Y { get => y; set => y = value; }
    public Boolean Fx { get => fx; set => fx = value; }
}

class Program
{
    //tree
    static Dictionary<int, probableNode> jTree = new Dictionary<int, probableNode>();
    //list of probableNodes
    static Dictionary<int, int> listprobNodes = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    //max capacity , id , goal state
    static int mx = 0, my = 0, id = 0, gx = 0, gy = 0;
    //flag
    static Boolean flag = false;


    //properties
    public static Dictionary<int, probableNode> JTree { get => jTree; set => jTree = value; }
    public static Dictionary<int, int> ListprobNodes { get => listprobNodes; set => listprobNodes = value; }
    public static int Mx { get => mx; set => mx = value; }
    public static int My { get => my; set => my = value; }
    public static int Gx { get => gx; set => gx = value; }
    public static int Gy { get => gy; set => gy = value; }
    public static int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public static bool Flag { get => flag; set => flag = value; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter jug capacity of x : ");
        Mx = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter jug capacity of y : ");
        My = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Goal state for the jugs : ");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Goal state for jug x : ");
        Gx = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Goal state for jug y : ");
        Gy = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please wait while the result is being processed...");

        createTree();

        var nodes = JTree.Values.Where(no => no.X.Equals(Gx) && no.Y.Equals(Gy));
        if(nodes != null)
        {
            var n = nodes.First();
            Console.WriteLine("Goal state exists! : ");
            List<int> goalPath = new List<int>();
            while(n.Id != 0)
            {
                goalPath.Add(n.Id);
                int previd = n.Previd;
                n = JTree[previd];
            }
            goalPath.Add(n.Id);
            goalPath.Reverse();

            foreach (int nid in goalPath)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("("+JTree[nid].X+","+JTree[nid].Y+")->");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goal state doesn't exists!");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void createTree()
    {
        probableNode root = new probableNode(id, id, 0, 0);
        JTree.Add(id, root);

        generateChildNodes(root, id);
    }

    public static void generateChildNodes(probableNode node, int pid)
    {
            int x = node.X;
            int y = node.Y;
            int cid = pid;
            probableNode pn = node;
            AddToX(pn, cid);
            pn = node;
            AddToY(node, cid);
            pn = node;
            TransferToX(node, cid);
            pn = node;
            TransferToY(node, cid);
            pn = node;
            EmptyX(node, cid);
            pn = node;
            EmptyY(node, cid);
            JTree[cid].Fx = true;
    }

    public static Boolean checkNode(probableNode node)
    {
        var nodes = JTree.Values.Where(no => no.X.Equals(node.X) && no.Y.Equals(node.Y));
        if (nodes == null)
        { 
            node.Previd = node.Id;
            JTree[id].Nextid.Add(id+1);
            id++;
            node.Id = id;
            JTree.Add(id, node);

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var n = nodes.First();
            if(node.Id != n.Id)
            {
                JTree[node.Id].Nextid.Add(n.Id);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
        public static void AddToX(probableNode node, int pid)
        {
        probableNode newn = new probableNode();
        newn = node;
            if (newn.X < Mx)
            {
                newn.X = Mx;
            }
            Boolean f = checkNode(newn);
            if (f == true)
            {
                generateChildNodes(newn, newn.Id);
            }
        }

        public static void AddToY(probableNode node, int pid)
        {
        probableNode newn = new probableNode();
        newn = node;
        if (newn.Y < My)
        {
            newn.Y = My;
        }
        Boolean f = checkNode(newn);
        if (f == true)
        {
            generateChildNodes(newn, newn.Id);
        }
    }

    public static void TransferToX(probableNode node, int pid)
    {
        probableNode newn = new probableNode();
        newn = node;
        newn.X += newn.Y;
        newn.Y = 0;
        if(newn.X > Mx)
        {
            newn.X = Mx;
        }
        Boolean f = checkNode(newn);
        if (f == true)
        {
            generateChildNodes(newn, newn.Id);
        }

    }

    public static void TransferToY(probableNode node, int pid)
    {
        probableNode newn = new probableNode();
        newn = node;
        newn.Y += newn.X;
        node.X = 0;
        if (newn.Y > My)
        {
            newn.Y = My;
        }
        Boolean f = checkNode(newn);
        if (f == true)
        {
            generateChildNodes(newn, newn.Id);
        }
    }

    public static void EmptyX(probableNode node, int pid)
    {
        probableNode newn = new probableNode();
        newn = node;
        newn.X = 0;
        Boolean f = checkNode(newn);
        if (f == true)
        {
            generateChildNodes(newn, newn.Id);
        }

    }

    public static void EmptyY(probableNode node, int pid)
    {
        probableNode newn = new probableNode();
        newn = node;
        newn.Y = 0;
        Boolean f = checkNode(newn);
        if (f == true)
        {
            generateChildNodes(newn, newn.Id);
        }

    }


}
```

}

Comment: You're mutating the object, not assigning it.

Comment: Why do you allocate a new `probableNode` object but not use it in the method `AddToX()`?

Comment: Classes are always passed by reference, not value

Comment: Here's a great article by Jon Skeet. http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @ChayimFriedman in this code I am experimenting as to how to make it pass as value and not as reference

Comment: @Magnetron so what should i do to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are reference types, so you're passing a reference to the object, not a copy of it. So, both the local variable and the caller are pointing to the same object.

When you do

```
probableNode newn = new probableNode();
newn = node;
```

What you're actual doing is make `newn` point to the same object that `node` and discarting `new probableNode()` that you just created. What you need is create a method to clone probableNode and call it to obtain a new object with the same values.

Edit:

The Clone method may be something like this:

```
public static probableNode Clone(probableNode pn)
{
    probableNode newPn = new probableNode();
    newPn.Id = pn.Id;
    newPn.Previd = pn.Previd;
    newPn.Nextid = new List<int>(pn.Nextid);
    newPn.X = pn.X;
    newPn.Y = pn.Y;
    newPn.Fx = pn.Fx;

    return newPn;
}
```

So you can make in your method

```
probableNode newn = probableNode.Clone(node);
```

Comment: Classes (or rather objects) are not always passed by reference - passing by reference is done using the `ref` or `out` modifiers. With reference types, the reference is passed by value by default.

Comment: @Lee classes are reference types, and as the name says, they're passed by reference. `ref` keywords on reference types only make it more clear but the behaviour will be the same with or without it. Exceptions are imutable classes, like string, that are also passed by reference, but as they're imutable, they only get modified in the local scope. Structs, on the other hand, are value types and are always passed by value, unless you use `ref` or `out` keywords

Comment: Well your idea worked out just fine. thanks @Magnetron

Comment: The name reference type 'suggests' they are passed by reference but they are not, references are passed by value by default. Variables are only passed by reference when using `ref` or `out`, and immutability is irrelevant. String references can be passed by value or by reference.

Comment: @Lee so what do you suggest I do ? This method worked out fine. but do you have a better way to address this problem ?

Comment: @kashishjhaveri - The suggested fix is fine, but 'classes are always passed by reference' is wrong, and pretty misleading in C# since it supports both reference types and pass by reference so the distinction can be important. See http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html for an explanation.

Comment: @Lee Ok, I agree with you. What I meant to say was that reference types don't pass a copy of the actual object, but reference to it, while value types pass a copy of it's value. So when you're modifying the same object in reference types. The part of my comment about `ref` and classes was wrong. When using the `ref` keyword you're passing the reference, as you said, and you can change the object that the original caller was referencing. I will change my answer to correct the terms. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a parameter that is typed as a reference type, and you pass it without an "out" or "ref" keyword, an object reference is passed by-value.  If, in the method, you change the object, well, the object that the caller's object reference references has been changed.  That's why it feels like you are "passing it by reference".  If you pass an instance of a reference type as "ref" or "out", you are passing the object reference "by reference".  In the called method, what that obj ref refers to can be changed and sent back to the caller